# Question regarding the correct way of implementing the squeeze theorem.

Tags: calculus, limits

When evaluating a limit with the squeeze theorem involving an odd function, say

$\lim_{x\to0}x^{5}\sin(1/x^{3})$

Obviously we can use the fact, $-1\le \sin(1/x^3) \le 1$

Then for $x\gt0$

$-x^5\le x^5\sin(1/x^3)\le x^5$

And for $x\lt0$

$x^5\le x^5\sin(1/x^3)\lt -x^5$

Now, is it better to define two functions $f(x),g(x)$ such that:

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^5, & \text{if $x\gt0$} \\
x^5, & \text{if $x\lt0$}
\end{cases}$
 where, $lim_{x\to 0}[f(x)]=0$

$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^5, & \text{if $x\gt0$} \\
-x^5, & \text{if $x\lt0$}
\end{cases}$
where, $lim_{x\to 0}[g(x)]=0$

And write:

$f(x)\le x^5\sin(1/x^3)\le g(x)$

And evaluate the limit using the squeeze theorem from there, or should we just evalute it from the first two inequalities. Also, are $f(x),g(x)$ correct as stated, should one of their components have a weak inequality rather than strict.

Answer (score 1):

or you write $$\left|x^5\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right|\le |x^5|$$ this tends to Zero for $x$ tends to zero